# Create a dictionary from lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists in python of the following structure:

```
list1 = [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4],[x5,y5],[x6,y6],[x7,y7],[x8,y8]]
list2 = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]
```

And I want to create a dictionary with keys of the second list and values of the first list, that looks like this:

```
{1: [[x1,y1], [x2,y2]],
 2: [[x3,y3], [x4,y4]],
 3: [[x5,y5], [x6,y6], [x7,y7]],
 4: [x8,y8]}
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in python?

I have used the zip command:

```
newlist = zip(list2, list1)
```

But now its not clear to me how to transform this in the dictionary I want.

Comment: Before asking for "the most efficient way", post what you've done.

Comment: As an aside, it really would have been helpful to post valid python for this example. As I copied it to work on a solution, I've realised I now have to go through and convert all those values to strings. Since you haven't shown what you tried yourself, I probably won't.

Comment: First do the basic for loop, then look at making it more efficient.

Comment: Apart form all the comments mentioned above, you also haven't mentioned the logic behind desired result

Comment: @SergeBallesta , I have updated my post now, I used zip but I dont know to transform it in the desired dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using external libraries, then I would recommend [`iteration_utilities.groupedby`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/groupedby.html) (disclosure: I'm the author of that library):

```
>>> list1= [['x1','y1'],['x2','y2'],['x3','y3'],['x4','y4'],['x5','y5'],['x6','y6'],['x7','y7'],['x8','y8']]
>>> list2 = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]

>>> from iteration_utilities import groupedby
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> groupedby(zip(list2, list1), key=itemgetter(0), keep=itemgetter(1))
{1: [['x1', 'y1'], ['x2', 'y2']],
 2: [['x3', 'y3'], ['x4', 'y4']],
 3: [['x5', 'y5'], ['x6', 'y6'], ['x7', 'y7']],
 4: [['x8', 'y8']]}
```

Under the hood it's like using a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), it just saves you the manual iteration.

---

If your `list2` is "sorted" you can also easily use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby

>>> {key: [i[1] for i in values] for key, values in groupby(zip(list2, list1), itemgetter(0))}
{1: [['x1', 'y1'], ['x2', 'y2']],
 2: [['x3', 'y3'], ['x4', 'y4']],
 3: [['x5', 'y5'], ['x6', 'y6'], ['x7', 'y7']],
 4: [['x8', 'y8']]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most optimized, but here's a compact piece of code that would do it:

```
vals = [["x1","y1"],["x2","y2"],["x3","y3"],["x4","y4"],["x5","y5"],["x6","y6"],["x7","y7"],["x8","y8"]]
keys = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4]

result = {}
for k,v in zip(keys,vals):
    result[k] = result.get(k, []) + [v]

# output: {1: [['x1', 'y1'], ['x2', 'y2']], 2: [['x3', 'y3'], ['x4', 'y4']], 3: [['x5', 'y5'], ['x6', 'y6'], ['x7', 'y7']], 4: [['x8', 'y8']]}
```

Comment: Another, possibly more efficient option for the inner loop: 

    result.setdefault(k, []).append(v)